# Clickhouse 'ninja' build error with "timestamp"

Tags: macos, build, build-error, clickhouse

Please help figure out what the problem when I tried build "ninja" for "ClickHouse"

> https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/ru/development/build_osx/

```
SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk   -D OS_DARWIN -nostdinc++ -MD -MT dbms/CMakeFiles/dbms.dir/src/Storages/LiveView/StorageLiveView.cpp.o -MF dbms/CMakeFiles/dbms.dir/src/Storages/LiveView/StorageLiveView.cpp.o.d -o dbms/CMakeFiles/dbms.dir/src/Storages/LiveView/StorageLiveView.cpp.o -c ../dbms/src/Storages/LiveView/StorageLiveView.cpp
In file included from ../dbms/src/Storages/LiveView/StorageLiveView.cpp:31:
../dbms/src/Storages/LiveView/LiveViewBlockInputStream.h:188:57: error: use of undeclared identifier 'timestamp'
        last_event_timestamp_usec = static_cast<UInt64>(timestamp.epochMicroseconds());
                                                        ^
1 error generated.
[3313/4079] Building CXX object dbms/CMakeFiles/dbms.dir/src/Client/ConnectionPoolWithFailover.cpp.o
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Also, I created a request here:
https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/8638

Comment: https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/8541

Comment: @DenisZhuravlev thank you for your answer but id definitely not the same problem. Thank you